# Output img src as text, not the image

Tags: reportlab

I'm building a PDF document using `reportlab`. I have a string that contains and image specifier that I want to output the text, not the image. The text is:

`<a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=66138&amp; clcid=0x409"><img src="welcome.png" alt="IIS7" width="571" height="411" /></a></div></body></html>`

I want this text printed as is. I'm getting the error:

> File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/reportlab/lib/utils.py", line 447, in open_for_read
>       raise IOError('Cannot open resource "%s"' % name)
>   IOError: Cannot open resource "welcome.png"
>   fileName='welcome.png' identity=[ImageReader@0x7f3a164d7050 filename='welcome.png']

It looks like reportlab sees the "img src" section and is trying to insert the image welcome.png. But I just want it to insert the text, not the image. Can this be done?
The line of code where this error occurs is:

```
story.append(Paragraph(host_vuln_array[INC][data_cnt][12], PS('body')))
```

The variable `host_vuln_array[INC][data_cnt][12]` contains the text.

Thanks.

I tried using

```
str(host_vuln_array[INC][data_cnt][12]) but that didn't work.
```

What I want in the PDF:

`<a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=66138&amp; clcid=0x409"><img src="welcome.png" alt="IIS7" width="571" height="411" /></a></div></body></html>`

What it seems to be trying to do:

Some text [welcome.png] more text.

Comment: `type(host_vuln_array[INC][data_cnt][12])` gives you what?

Comment: The output is <type 'str'>.

Comment: I get the same error with `platypus`, but it works in `canvas`. Have you consider using `canvas` instead of `platypus` to build the pdf?

Comment: I'm building a report with a clickable table of contents. Can this be done with canvas?

Comment: Yes. Maybe it'll be more complicated to draw everything with `canvas`, but it is defintely possible.